# Calling functions on directive controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to call a function on a directive controller, accessing the instance using it's id, from the parent controller:

```
<my-directive id="id1" />
```

```js
var dirController = getDirectiveByID("id1");
dirController.someFunc();
```

What in your opinion is the simplest way of doing this?
Most solutions I've looked at are ugly/over complicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what you trying to achieve, unfortunately if you want to expose controller API from **Directive** specifically, the proper way I know is using `require` in **Directive** but it is for **Directive** to **Directive** and downward only.

Since your `my-directive` can access parent scope, presumably it inherits from parent scope, the easiest way to achieve what you want is initialise an object as control interface inside your parent controller

```
$scope.control = {};
```

then inside your `myDirective` append functions you want to expose to that control interface, e.g.

```
$scope.control.someFn = function() {
   ...
}
```

thus in your parent controller you should be able to access those function you exposed from directive.

Comment: Hi Brian,
Thanks for your reply. In my directive I use isolated scope. Is it possible to access the parent controller scope in this case?

Comment: By parent controller scope I mean the main controller on the page, not a parent directive for which I could require.

Comment: One possibility from another post is:

Comment: angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope().get()

Comment: Yes, you still can access parent scope by `$scope.$parent` insider your directive, or instead you can just add a new attribute `control="control"` to your directive and insider your directive add `control: '='` to the `scope` then you should be able to access `$scope.control`.

Comment: You do can get **scope** from element but that would be overkilled since you search entire DOM to find that directive element, also you need to make sure the timing when get the element is already complied and linked which I don't think there has any robust to do that.

Comment: What I suggest is, if the functions are **generic** and **reusable** make it as service functions, otherwise just take advantages of scope inheritance and object reference would solve your problem nicely.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: No worries, David. Would be good if you can vote only if you think my answers are useful and help.

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is to register the directives in the controller, then fire the function you need (like in the observer pattern).

here is an example, you find it en [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reduno/gan7Lyjf/6/) too

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="parentController" >
    <h1>
      {{title}}
    </h1>
    <child id="John"></child>
    <child id="Heisenberg"></child>
    <child id="Red"></child>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="c in childs">
        I'm {{c.scope.nameFunction()}}
        <button ng-click="fireFunction(c.id,'nameFunction')">Say my name</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("parentController", function($scope,$rootScope){
    $scope.title = "Title";
  $scope.childs=[];
  $scope.fireFunction = function(id, functionName){
    for(i=0; i<$scope.childs.length; i++)
    { 
        if($scope.childs[i].id===id){
             window.alert($scope.childs[i].scope[functionName]());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('child', function() {
  var __controller__ = {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
        id:"@"
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs)  {
        console.log(attrs.id);
      $scope.$parent.childs.push({id:attrs.id, scope: $scope});
      $scope.nameFunction = function(){
        return $scope.id
        }
    },
    template: '<div>' + 'Hello Dad ! i am is {{id}}' +'</div>'
  }
  return __controller__
})
```